# How to scroll content in Flash 8?

Tags: flash, scrollbar

I have several scenes in a Flash app; for some of them the Movie height is right while for others the content is very long so i would need to have scrollbars to let the user scroll down.
Which is the correct way to handle it in this old version of Flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your movieclip in the ScrollPane component.

```
var _sp:ScrollPane = new ScrollPane();    
this.addChild(_sp);
_sp.setSize(400,400);

var _container:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(_container);

_sp.source=_container;
```

http://www.tizag.com/flashTutorial/flashtextscroll.php
http://www.entheosweb.com/flash/scrolling_content.asp

Comment: addChild? Sprite? In Flash 8? Only your second URL is in-topic.

Comment: Thanks, the second link was really useful!